# Basic authorization command for curl

Tags: curl, authorization, basic-authentication

How do I set up the Basic authorization using Base64 encoded credentials?

I tried the below two commands, but of no use. Please suggest me the correct variant.

```bash
curl -i -H 'Accept:application/json' Authorization:Basic <username:password> http://example.com
curl -i -H 'Accept:application/json' Authorization:Basic.base64_encode(username:password) http://example.com
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the `-H` header again before the Authorization:Basic things. So it will be

```bash
curl -i \
    -H 'Accept:application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization:Basic BASE64_string' \
    http://example.com
```

Here, `BASE64_string` = Base64 of `username:password`

Comment: Except of course that '"username:password" has to be base64 encoded and not plain as shown here...

Comment: @DanielStenberg that's the one! that's why my request was failing, good call.

Comment: There should be a whitespace after the colon. ex: `Authorization: Basic BASE64_string`

Answer (score 99):

> How do I set up the basic authorization?

All you need to do is use `-u, --user USER[:PASSWORD]`. Behind the scenes `curl` builds the `Authorization` header with base64 encoded credentials for you.

Example:

```bash
curl -u username:password -i -H 'Accept:application/json' http://example.com
```

Comment: In this case header looks like "Authorization: Basic base64(<login>:<password>)? What I'm trying to unserstand is the meaning of symbols that follow the "Basic" word :)

Answer (score 44):

#### Background

You can use the `base64` CLI tool to generate the base64 encoded version of your username + password like this:

```bash
$ echo -n "joeuser:secretpass" | base64
am9ldXNlcjpzZWNyZXRwYXNz

-or-

$ base64 <<<"joeuser:secretpass"
am9ldXNlcjpzZWNyZXRwYXNzCg==
```

Base64 is reversible so you can also decode it to confirm like this:

```bash
$ echo -n "joeuser:secretpass" | base64 | base64 -D
joeuser:secretpass

-or-

$ base64 <<<"joeuser:secretpass" | base64 -D
joeuser:secretpass
```

**NOTE:** *username = joeuser*, *password = secretpass*

#### Example #1 - using -H

You can put this together into `curl` like this:

```bash
$ curl -H "Authorization: Basic $(base64 <<<"joeuser:secretpass")" http://example.com
```

#### Example #2 - using -u

Most will likely agree that if you're going to bother doing this, then you might as well just use `curl`'s `-u` option.

> ```
> $ curl --help |grep -- "--user "
>  -u, --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password
> ```

For example:

```
$ curl -u someuser:secretpass http://example.com
```

But you can do this in a semi-safer manner if you keep your credentials in a encrypted vault service such as [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/) or [Pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/).

For example, here I'm using the LastPass' CLI tool, `lpass`, to retrieve my credentials:

```
$ curl -u $(lpass show --username example.com):$(lpass show --password example.com) \
     http://example.com
```

#### Example #3 - using curl config

There's an even safer way to hand your credentials off to `curl` though. This method makes use of the `-K` switch.

```bash
$ curl -X GET -K \
    <(cat <<<"user = \"$(lpass show --username example.com):$(lpass show --password example.com)\"") \
    http://example.com
```

When used, your details remain hidden, since they're passed to `curl` via a temporary file descriptor, for example:

```
+ curl -skK /dev/fd/63 -XGET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://es-data-01a.example.com:9200/_cat/health
++ cat
+++ lpass show --username example.com
+++ lpass show --password example.com
1561075296 00:01:36 rdu-es-01 green 9 6 2171 1085 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%
```

**NOTE:** Above I'm communicating with one of our Elasticsearch nodes, inquiring about the cluster's health.

This method is dynamically creating a file with the contents `user = "<username>:<password>"` and giving that to `curl`.

#### HTTP Basic Authorization

The methods shown above are facilitating a feature known as Basic Authorization that's part of the HTTP standard.

> When the user agent wants to send authentication credentials to the
> server, it may use the Authorization field.
>
> The Authorization field is constructed as follows:
>
> 1. The username and password are combined with a single colon (:).
>    This means that the username itself cannot contain a colon.
> 2. The resulting string is encoded into an octet sequence. The character set
>    to use for this encoding is by default unspecified, as
>    long as it is compatible with US-ASCII, but the server may suggest use
>    of UTF-8 by sending the charset parameter.
> 3. The resulting string is encoded using a variant of Base64.
> 4. The authorization method and a space (e.g. "Basic ") is then prepended to
>    the encoded string.
>
> For example, if the browser uses Aladdin as the username and
> OpenSesame as the password, then the field's value is the
> base64-encoding of Aladdin:OpenSesame, or QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l.
> Then the Authorization header will appear as:
>
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l

*Source: [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side)*

Comment: Just a little nitpicking, but you don't decrypt a base64 string, it's decoding :)

Comment: Also `-w0` should be used for `base64` command in order to disable line wrapping.

Comment: Why nobody asked about the notable difference between the outcome of two first examples?

Answer (score 24):

One way, provide `--user` flag as part of `curl`, as follows:

```
curl --user username:password http://example.com
```

Another way is to get [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded token of **"username:password"** from any online website like - https://www.base64encode.org/ and pass it as `Authorization` header of `curl` as follows:

```bash
curl -i -H 'Authorization:Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' http://localhost:8080/
```

Here, `dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` is `Base64` encoded token of `username:password`.

Comment: thanks your for your information of base64 encoded token

Comment: And please don't use an online website to encode your passwords, folks. Use `echo -n "password" | base64`.

Comment: You need to encode both user + pass: `echo -n "username:password" | base64`.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen for big Intranets, that you will need the base64(domain/user:password).

Answer (score -6):

> curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects

```
--note

base46 encode =ZnJlZDpmcmVk
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly and put some explanation.