# curl command to check authentification in FOSRestBundle?

Tags: rest, authentication, curl, basic-authentication, fosuserbundle

The FOSRestBundle is working perfectly in my project but without authentification. Now, my goal is to make my requests with auth.

To do so, I added this firewall in security.yml

```
firewalls:
    # ...    
    rest_api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        http_basic:
            provider: fos_userbundle
    # ...    
access_control:
    # ...    
    - { path: ^/api/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

To check this, I used this shell command:

```
curl -i http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/api/test/1
```

The result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 13:56:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=4dtr168vmj1eg523a07kbkjkh1; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/login
Vary: Accept-Language
X-Debug-Token: 220df7
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/login">http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the returned code is 302 FOUND since it is URL is redirected to `http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/login` as I am using FOSUserBundle.

Now, I want to check if the authenfication is working well. I tried this: `curl -i http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/api/test/1 --user user:password` but still I have 302 FOUND.

I tried this also `curl -i -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Authorization:Basic username:password' http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/api/test/1` but still I have 302 FOUND.

So is there any proposal of curl command to check the auth in my REST api?

Thanks,

**Notice:** I have tried solutions in many links like: [basic authorization command for curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803339/basic-authorization-command-for-curl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found!

All you have to do is:

1. Change the firewall like this:

firewalls:

```
# ...    
rest_api:
    # pattern: ^/api/ # to be changed as in the next line
    pattern: /api/.*  # the correct way
    stateless: true
    http_basic:
        provider: fos_userbundle
    # ...    
access_control:
    # ...    
    # - { path: ^/api/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY } # to be removed
```

1. For the curl command, it has to be like this:

`curl -i -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Authorization:Basic YW1pbmU6c3RpZ21hdGFn' http://localhost/tuto/web/app_dev.php/api/test/1`

where YW1pbmU6c3RpZ21hdGFn is the result of encoding 'user:password' in [base64](http://www.base64encode.org/).

Hope it will help others.

Comment: Thanks, the hint with base64 helped me. For some reason cURL does not generate base64 if you use "-u user:password"